# Latex nested loop not displaying correctly

Tags: algorithm, latex

Hi I'm new to latex I use here the Algorithmic package to write my pseudo code the problem I faced is that 'some text' is displayed correctly under the second loop but the 'return' statement which needs to be outside the first for loop isn't showing correctly also it does not mark the end of each loop (the vertical tic is missing), the execution result is shown in the image:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8,linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage {algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algcompatible}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\ContinuedFloat

\caption{My algorithm}
\textbf{Input:} solution,bound, data\_matrix, vehicle\_capacity, demand\_data,k\_max,operations\_data, move\_type,tenure, max\_number\_of\_moves,max\_iter,non\_improvement\_maxiter,itermax,epsilon\\
\textbf{Output:} $best$ $solution$ \\[0.1in]

routes = extract routes from \textbf{solution}\\
oldfitness = fitness(\textbf{solution})\\

ls\_move\_type = inversion\\
best\_solution = routes\\[0.1in]

\For{0 \leq i \leq itermax}{
    new\_routes = [ ]\\
    desc = 'normal route'\\
    
    
    \For{route \textbf{in} routes}{
        n=length(route)\\
        comb = int($\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}$)\\
        \If{n \geq 4}{
            tabu\_list\_tenure = $\frac{comb}{5}$\\
            ls\_maxiteration = 50 \\
            ls\_move\_type = 'inversion'\\
        }
        \If{3 \leq n \leq 4}{
            tabu\_list_tenure = $\frac{comb}{4}$ \\
            ls\_maxiteration = 25\\
            ls\_move\_type = 'relocation'\\
        }
       \Else{
         append \textbf{route} to \textbf{new\_routes}\\
         desc = 'short route'\\
        }\\[0.1in]
        }
        
        
    some action
    
        
        
        
    }



return






\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in wondering about the output as long as you get errors in your .log file. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output.

Some of the most critical problems:

- never ignore error messages!
- `utf8` isn't a valid option for the `algorithm2e` package
- `\ContinuedFloat` is not defined by default. If you want to use it, you need a package which defines it. Maybe you want to use the `caption` package?
- never ever use math mode to fake italic text as in `$best$ $solution$`. This completely messes up the kerning
- some of your `_` are not escaped
- you mustn't use math commands like `0 \leq i \leq` outside of math mode
- use something like `\Return` to properly format it
- using `\\` for line breaks is already quite questionable, but using them two times in a row is simply an error.
- because one can't say it often enough: never ignore error messages!

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
%utf8,
linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage {algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algcompatible}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
%\ContinuedFloat
\caption{My algorithm}
\textbf{Input:} solution,bound, data\_matrix, vehicle\_capacity, demand\_data,k\_max,operations\_data, move\_type,tenure, max\_number\_of\_moves,max\_iter,non\_improvement\_maxiter,itermax,epsilon

\textbf{Output:} \emph{best solution}

\medskip

routes = extract routes from \textbf{solution}

oldfitness = fitness(\textbf{solution})

ls\_move\_type = inversion

best\_solution = routes

\medskip

\For{$0 \leq i \leq$ itermax}{
    new\_routes = [ ]
    
    desc = 'normal route'
    
    \For{route \textbf{in} routes}{
        n=length(route)
        
        comb = int($\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}$)
        
        \If{$n \geq 4$}{
            tabu\_list\_tenure = $\frac{comb}{5}$
            
            ls\_maxiteration = 50 
            
            ls\_move\_type = 'inversion'
        }
        \If{$3 \leq n \leq 4$}{
            tabu\_list\_tenure = $\frac{comb}{4}$
            
            ls\_maxiteration = 25
            
            ls\_move\_type = 'relocation'
        }
       \Else{
         append \textbf{route} to \textbf{new\_routes}
         
         desc = 'short route'         
        }
        
        \medskip
        
        }
    some action   
    }
\Return
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your response, I tried the  ` \Return` but it didn't solve the problem, I've used same methods in other algorithms and they displayed correctly in the same file and one of the algorithms had a `while else` statement and multiple nested loops this is the first time I face this strange problem :( .

Comment: @Farouk Did you fix all other errors as well?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to go to new line the only way I found is this, I'm not using Algorithm2e syntax I just used algorithmic to write the algorithm so there is no indicator for the algorithm to jump to next line, if I don't add \\ the Latex won't jump unless there is a keyword such as For, while, ... As I told you it's my first time using Latex to write just the algorithm that I used.

Comment: @Farouk A new line in latex is very simple: insert an empty

Comment: Yes, in paragraphs but in algorithmic environnement it's not the same if you just skipped to next line he will consider as if you are in the same line. I've tried that.

Comment: @Farouk Empty lines work just fine, see my edited code